# Best way to check if JS variable is / isn't more than one value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next, ecma

I often write this repetitive code:

```
if (SERVER_ENV == "TEST" || SERVER_ENV == "PROD" || SERVER_ENV == "QA") {
  // ...
}
```

Is there a better way to write conditional checks like this in Javascript? When you need to check against more than one pre-defined value.

I mean, I could do:

```
const POSSIBLE_ENVS = ["TEST","PROD","QA"];

if (POSSIBLE_ENVS.includes(SERVER_ENV))

// OR

if (POSSIBLE_ENVS.indexOf(SERVER_ENV) >= 0)
```

But that is cumbersome and it inverts my logical thinking. I'm writing `does that array contain my value ?` instead of `is my value inside that array ?`

How to people usually handle this? Is there a ECMA proposal or any other syntactical sugar available?

Comment: Side-note: you probably should be using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Well, a `switch` statement, but that's not a succinct expression.

Comment: Use `includes`. Deal with it. JavaScript isn't going to be pretty all the time, sausage has to get made.

Comment: Thank you all. Will delete this question.

Comment: You could also define a new function property on `String.prototype.oneOf = ( values... ) => values.includes( this );` and used like `if( SERVER_ENV.oneOf( "TEST", "PROD", "QA" ) ) { ...`

Comment: If you're doing a lot of tests use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).